# Let $X \sim \text{Geo}(p_1)$ and $Y \sim\text{Geo}(p_2)$. What is $E(X\mid X \leq Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation

I'm not sure how to solve this question, but my intuition would be that we would sum up

$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} (x * P(X=x\mid X \leq Y))$, but I would still be stick with a conditional probability.

Is there a general approach to solving conditional expectations between two different distributions?

Comment: A good start. Then you continue to compute the conditional pmf by definition of conditional probability.

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition of conditional probability,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X\mid X\leqslant Y] &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\mathbb P(X=k\mid X\leqslant Y)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\frac{\mathbb P(\{X=k\}\cap \{X\leqslant Y\})}{\mathbb P(X\leqslant Y)}.
\end{align}
Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\leqslant Y)&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(\{ X\leqslant Y\}\cap\{X=k\})\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X=k) \sum_{j=k}^\infty \mathbb P(Y=j)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p_1)^{k-1}p_1 \sum_{j=k}^\infty (1-p_2)^{j-1}p_2\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p_1)^{k-1}p_1 (1-p_2)^{j-1}\\
&= p_1\sum_{k=1}^\infty ((1-p_1)(1-p_2))^{k-1}\\
&= \frac{p_1}{1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}.
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X\mid X\leqslant Y] &= \frac{1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}{p_1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k (1-p_1)^{k-1}p_1\sum_{j=k}^\infty (1-p_2)^{j-1}p_2\\
&=(1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2))\sum_{k=1}^\infty k (1-p_1)^{k-1}(1-p_2)^{k-1}\\
&=(1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)) \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) ((1-p_1)(1-p_2))^k\\
&= \frac1{1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Nice and clear cut answer. There seems to be a typo for $\mathbb P(X\leqslant Y)$: on the 3rd-to-last line, after the the inner summation, the exoponent for $(1 - p_2)$ should be $k-1$ and not $j-1$.  I will remove this comment after the typo is corrected.